# How to limit the child retrieved in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to ask about how to retrieve data with limited child in Android Firebase. Here is my data structure :

```
"chatrooms":
    "chatroom_id_1" :
        "message":
            "message_id_1":1
            "message_id_2":1
            "message_id_3":1
            "message_id_4":1
            "message_id_5":1
            "message_id_6":1
            "message_id_7":1
            "message_id_8":1
            "message_id_9":1
            "message_id_10":1
            "message_id_11":1
    "chatroom_id_2" :
            "message":
                "message_id_12":1
                "message_id_13":1
                "message_id_14":1
                "message_id_15":1
                "message_id_16":1
                "message_id_17":1
                "message_id_18":1
                "message_id_19":1
                "message_id_20":1
                "message_id_21":1
                "message_id_22":1
```

From the structure above how to do the query to retrieve a snapshot with only data limited to 5 messages?

The dataSnapshot I would like to have is like this :

```
DataSnapshot { 
    key = chatroom_id_1, 
    value = {
        messages={
            message_id_1=1,
            message_id_2=1,
            message_id_3=1,
            message_id_4=1,
            message_id_5=1
        }
    }
}
DataSnapshot { 
        key = chatroom_id_2, 
        value = {
            messages={
                message_id_12=1,
                message_id_13=1,
                message_id_14=1,
                message_id_15=1,
                message_id_16=1
            }
        }
    }
```

is it possible to do so? Because most of the tutorial I've found can only limit the child retrieved but not the inner child. Thanks

EDIT : MY message_id is generated randomly, so to obtain the message_id I have to use an DataSnapshot with iterator . Here's my retrieve data code

```
public void retrieveChatRoom(final Callback callback){
        DatabaseReference ref = reference.child("chatrooms");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                callback.onDataChanged();
                Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = (DataSnapshot) i.next();
                    callback.dataReceived(dataSnapshot1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

the thing is the DataSnapshot return all of the chat_message inside my chatroom,can I limit it to only returning 5 messages?

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve a subset of the child nodes, you use [Firebase queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). If you want to synchronize the child nodes up to a certain key, you'd use:

```
Query query = ref.child("chatroom_id_1/message")
    .orderByKey()
    .endAt("message_id_5");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
    }
  }
  ...
```

If you're just looking to get 5 messages from a location:

```
Query query = ref.child("chatroom_id_1/message")
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToFist(5);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
    }
  }
  ...
```

**Update**:

Firebase Database queries can limit the results based on a fixed property (or path) of each child node of the location where you execute them. There is no way to retrieve the last 5 messages for each chat room in one go. You can either retrieve the last 5 messages for a specific chat room. Or the last 5 chat rooms.

Comment: from your answer it means that we have to know the chatroom_id key and message_id key? In my case the key is generated randomly , so I don't know both the key of chatroom and message. Is there any way to do it without us knowing the chatroom_id and message_id?

Comment: If you don't know that chatroom ID, how do you know from which room to retrieve the messages?

Comment: I'm using the iterator to retrieve my chatroom_id from datasnapshot. The problem is the datasnapshot return all child items inside it. What I want to do is to limit the child returned to only 5 child. Thanks

Comment: I added a guess to what you might need there. But if that still doesn't answer your question, update your question (with the edit link under it) to include the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most of us trying to help here are better at reading code than descriptions of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to do, Your current database structure is not ideal for these kinds of querying.

You need to "denormalize" your data.
Rather than storing all messages inside chatrooms break them apart.

The trick is to store all your messages separately as a list under the "chatroom_id". That way you can easily fetch all messages for a given chatroom and use firebase limit apis as well.

Something like

```
/chatrooms
    - chatroom_id1
        {
            name,
            last_message,
            timestamp
        }

/messages
    - chatroom_id   //<-- Notice this
        {
            sender,
            content,
            timestamp
        }           //<-- Add new child messages here
```

You can then get messages for a given chatroom_id something like

```
//Get chatroom list and details
ref.child("chatrooms")
ref.child("chatrooms").child("some_chatroom_id")

//Get limited messages
ref.child("messages").child("some_chatroom_id").limitToFirst(10)
```

This will have additional benefit of reducing bandwidth usage when you just need a list of chatrooms since then the entire messages list won't be fetched.

[Firebase Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)